# Linq query to merge child if parent id is same

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class

```
public class SelectionModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

public class RiskFactorModel
    {
        public SelectionModel RiskFactor { get; set; }

        public int? RiskFactorIdParent { get; set; }

        public List<string> RiskFactorNameChild { get; set; }
    }


    public List<RiskFactorModel> LowRiskFactorModel { get; set; }
```

I want to update the LowRiskFactorModel.
Check each Value(under SelectionModel), if two or more are same, then merge RiskFactorNameChild into one.

How can I do it in Linq?

Comment: And what happens to `RiskFactorIdParent`? How should this be merged?

Comment: This can be the same value, like the RiskFactor . Only the Child need to be merged.

Comment: Ok updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx), grouping the elements by the `SelectionModel.Value` and then creating new `RiskFactorModel`s combining the child names of all elements in a group:

```
var groupedModels = LowRiskFactorModel.GroupBy(m => m.RiskFactor.Value);
var mergedModels = groupedModels.Select(g => 
    new RiskFactorModel
    {
        RiskFactor = g.First().RiskFactor,
        RiskFactorIdParent = g.First().RiskFactorIdParent,
        RiskFactorNameChild = g.SelectMany(m => m.RiskFactorNameChild).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

The result is a `List<RiskFactorModel>` containing one element per `RiskFactor.Value` with a `RiskFactorNameChild` list containing all the combined lists of all source elements with that name.

Comment: Sorry @Rene , I should have added the complete model. I understand the SelectMany, but was unable to get final model. Can you please see the updated model.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    public class RiskFactorModel
    {
        public static List<RiskFactorModel> LowRiskFactorModel { get; set; }

        public string RiskFactorName { get; set; }
        public List<string> RiskFactorNameChild { get; set; }


        public void Update()
        {
            var groups = LowRiskFactorModel.GroupBy(x => x.RiskFactorName).ToList();

            LowRiskFactorModel = groups.Select(x => new RiskFactorModel()
            {
                RiskFactorName = x.Key,
                RiskFactorNameChild = x.Select(y => y.RiskFactorNameChild.Select(z => z)).SelectMany(y => y).Distinct().ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }

    }
```